# Mozilla border-radius in a table not working consistently

Tags: css

Driving myself nuts here!.

Firstly can I just clarify that it is no longer necessary to prefix border radius eg with -moz-. But is it good practice to do so in case an old browser is employed?

Secondly I accept that in employing a border radius inside a table demands that border-collapse is not collapse I also believe that border-spacing should not be 0.

The following draft CSS & HTML creates nicely rounded table elements in all browsers except mozilla where for some reason the table is rounded the th is rounded BUT the td's are all square.

Fire bug reports that the radius is applied. Indeed if I place a background colour on td I can see that this background is rounded. But it still displays the remainder as square.

Any thoughts ???

```css
/* borders */

#booking_Form_Wrapper{
    border: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

#booking_Table{
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    background-color: #a5a5a5;
    border-radius: 14px;
    border-spacing: 6px 6px;
}

#booking_Table th{
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#booking_Table td{
    border-radius: 10px;
}

/* other styles */
```

HTML

```
<table id="booking_Table"> 
    <thead id="booking_Title">
        <th>
            Booking
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="booking_Session">
            <td>
                <a>Class - Level</a><br />
                <a>Day and Date</a><br />
                <a>Start Time - End Time</a>
            </td>                   
        </tr>
        <tr id="booking_XXXXXXX">
            <td style="border-radius: 6px;">
                <label>Do you want to XXXXXXXX</label><input type="checkbox"/>
                <label>XXX</label><input type="radio" name="XXX" value="b">
                <label>XXX</label><input type="radio" name="XXX" value="s">
                <label>XXX</label><input type="radio" name="XXX" value="r">
            </td>           
        </tr>
        <tr id="booking_Cancel">
            <td>                
            <P><span>Cancellation Policy</span> - xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</P>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="form_Footer">
            <td>
                <input class="form_Submit" type="submit" name="submit" value="Make Booking"/>
                <input class="form_Cancel" type="cancel" name="cancel" value="Cancel"/>
            </td>
        </tr> <!-- form footer -->
    </tbody>
</table> <!-- booking table -->
```

[image]

Here is the firebug computed style info for the first square td

[image]

Comment: I see rounded corners in Firefox and Chrome, see jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5JC2Z/2/

Comment: What version of FF is giving you a trouble? It seems fine to me on FF 14.01 http://jsfiddle.net/5JC2Z/3/

Comment: Hi @IliaRostovtsev sadly I don't hence the edit above. Double checked firebug the styling and computed states that this should be rounded but it isn't.

Comment: Displaying rounded corners for me in the fiddles from comments, FF 15.0 on Win7 64 bit. Have you tried disabling addons yet?

Comment: I have to go out. Before her in doors gets mad at me. Will look in later. Probably need to think about something else for a while anyway.

Comment: Just installed FF15. Everything works fine!

Comment: Hi @Jeroen, No I haven't tried that. I have completely Isolated this table from everything else. I still get square td's This is nuts. You guys do not see this issue. I do not see the issue is fiddle but I do in FF. So I will have a go at removing add ons.

Comment: (not sure if I understand your last comment...) but if you *don't* see it in the fiddle, and you *do* see it in your site... chances are there's something different between the two that's causing the problem ;) (meaning it's not addons)

Comment: @Jeroen  OK so I have uninstalled and reinstalled firefox thus starting with a clean sheet with regard to addon's and the problem is still there. So back to the drawing board.

Comment: Hi @Jeroen Ok I have found the problem. I just couldn't see it for looking too hard! If you apply a height to the container i.e. the <tr> this causes the td to square off. As per the moz developer notes the radius is applied to the background even if no border applied. I had given the <tr> with the same class a height in another linked CSS file. Many thanks for looking at this apologies for the mistake. The interesting thing is that the other browsers did not object to this and rounded of the <td> regardless.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev Please see comment above. Many thanks for your input.

Comment: @codepuppy Good luck to you then!;)

Comment: @codepuppy good to hear you solved it, don't forget to answer your own question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution - I may not be stating this in the correct technical terms but the effect was caused in FF by giving the containing element a height. In my case the `<tr>`. The interesting thing is that none of the other browsers complain about this and round the `<td>` regardless. I think that this is connected to the mozilla developer notes which say that the radius is applied to the background of the element where the radius is applied regardless of whether a border is specified or not. The `<tr>` was not part of the background and so was not rounded.

Anyway don't give the container a height and everything good.